# Problem opening .robot from .exe generated with pyinstaller

Tags: python, robotframework, pyinstaller

Generate a .exe with pyinstaller the following command:
`pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "index.robot;."  --noconsole index.py`
but doing so with the flag of --noconsole returns this error `Command '['robot','C:Users\\pathl\\index.robot']' returned non-zero exit status 120.`

But if I omit the --noconsole flag it does work

The path of my .robot that I pass to the command I get from the following function:

```
    def resource_path(self, relative_path):
        try:
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
            print("Meipass", base_path)
        except:
            base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
        
        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

And this is the function that generates the error for me

```
    def execute_robot_framework(self, object_key, local_directory):
        try:
            name_file_ctf = os.path.basename(object_key)

            if os.path.exists(self.temp_logs_name):
                os.remove(self.temp_logs_name)
        
            logFile = open(self.temp_logs_name, 'w') 
            subprocess.run(['robot', self.directory_file_robot ], stdout=logFile, check=True)

        except Exception as error:
            self.log(f" {error}")
            print(error)
```

I also tried this way but I still get an error:

```
    def execute_robot(self):
        try:
            logFile = open(self.temp_logs_name, 'w') 
            robot.run(self.directory_file_robot, stdout=logFile)
        except Exception as error:
            self.log(f" {error}")
            print(error)
```

and with this function I get this error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`

I wish I could pass the --noconsole flag since I do have a GUI in the script.